# Launch build script from Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, installshield

I am trying to create a windows service to build my application using Install Shield.

I have application being built and then I want to send a message to the service so that it can start the packaging behind the scenes, without user interaction, and update once the build is done.

I am creating a new Process and launching my build script but it fails.
I selected the option to not create a separate window etc but it does not work. Any bright ideas?

Comment: It's unclear from the description exactly what is failing, and if you're getting any sort of error message or event.

Comment: I do not see any error message. The process is just not launched.

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason you are rolling your own?  Why not just use Cruise Control, Jenkins, Hudson, TFS Team Build, BuildForge et al?

Comment: We have different machines for Creating package and building (Courtesy Corporate policy). So I want to have an automated system which would ping the service on the other machine and the service would in turn initiate process to start the packaging using Install Shield.

Comment: Systems like BuildForge can do that out of the box.  You have the concept of a build controller and build agent and the build controller can delegate build steps to different machines.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything showing up in Event Viewer? Failing that, you might try to start your service with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) running to see what's failing.